# Write a shell script for importing file CSV files into a postgres table

Tags: postgresql-9.4

We are using Postgres 9.4. Following is the requirement.

Can Anyone share me the shell script for importing CSV files into a table.

Which ever CSV file import is done then it should be moved to different directory.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider [Loading CSV Data with pgloader](http://pgloader.io/howto/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have written like below. And its working fine.

For all CSV to 1 table

```
cd /tmp--Files are located in /tmp folder

for x in $(ls /tmp/*.csv); 
do PGPASSWORD=psqlpassword psql  -U pega -c "copy table_name from '/tmp/$x' csv" -h <dbhost>; done
mv /tmp/*.csv /backup_folder/
```